# Handling custom C++ exceptions in Cython

Tags: c++, exception, cython

I have some trouble handling custom C++ exceptions when calling from Cython.
My situation is the following: I have a library that uses `CustomLibraryException` for all exceptions. What I want is basically get the error message and raise a Python error with it.

The [user guide](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions) has some hints but it is a bit unspecific.
The first possibility is to do:

cdef int bar() except +ValueError

This converts the `CustomLibraryException` to a `ValueError`, but loses the error message.

The other possibility is to explicitly convert the error using

```
cdef int raise_py_error()
cdef int something_dangerous() except +raise_py_error
```

I don't really understant this solution. I understood that raise_py_error has to be a C++ function that somehow handles the error. I am not sure how to handle it though. The function doesn't get an argument and is called inside the `catch` block in C++.

If any one has an working example of handling a C++ exception in Cython, that would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `CustomLibraryException` derives from `std::runtime_error` (as a well-behaved C++ exception should), then the behavior you're seeing is a bug in Cython.

If it doesn't, then the easiest thing to do is to wrap the C++ function you're calling in a C++ helper function that translates the exception:

```
double foo(char const *, Bla const &);  // this is the one we're wrapping

double foo_that_throws_runtime_error(char const *str, Bla const &blaref)
{
    try {
        return foo(str, blaref);
    } catch (CustomLibraryException const &e) {
        throw std::runtime_error(e.get_the_message());
    }
}
```

This will cause a `RuntimeError` to be raised on the Python side. Alternatively, `throw` an `std::invalid_argument` to `raise` a `ValueError`, etc. (see the table in the page you linked to).

Comment: The exception doesn't derive from ``std::runtime`` as you expected. Thanks for the help :) That doesn't make it that much better, though. The functions raising the error are member-functions and I don't want to change their code. This is about my [gco wrappers](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.de/2012/05/graphcuts-for-python-pygco.html) and the license doesn't allow me to redistribute :-/

Comment: @AndreasMueller: member functions can be quite easily wrapped in freestanding functions; just pass the object they should operate on as the first argument: `void wrapper(Obj &o, int ham) { return o.wrapped(ham); }`

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just to lazy to do it yet ;)
Btw, did you know you are the top 100th poster on SO?

Comment: @AndreasMueller: I'm hardly surprised. I spend way too much time here :)

Answer (score 9):

Agreed the wording in the doc page leaves something to be desired. While "*Cython cannot throw C++ exceptions*", here is a raise_py_error that does what we want.

First, define the custom exception class in cython and make a handle to it using the "public" keyword

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject

class JMapError(RuntimeError):
  pass

cdef public PyObject* jmaperror = <PyObject*>JMapError
```

Then write the exception handler (the docs aren't super clear this must be written in C++ and imported):

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "jmap/cy_utils.H"
#include "jmap/errors.H"
#include <exception>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern PyObject *jmaperror;

void raise_py_error()
{
  try {
    throw;
  } catch (JMapError& e) {
    string msg = ::to_string(e.code()) +" "+ e.what();
    PyErr_SetString(jmaperror, msg.c_str());
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what() );
  }
}
```

Finally, bring the handler into cython with an extern block, and use it:

```
cdef extern from "jmap/cy_utils.H":
  cdef void raise_py_error()

void _connect "connect"() except +raise_py_error
```

Done. I now see new exception, constructed with the error code as intended:

```
JMapError: 520 timed connect failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: Interresting answer. Do you know if it is possible to make cython compile that c++ file directly or do I need to manually make a lib then link against it? I could not find any documentation on this...

Comment: I found out. Here is a minimal example of error handling while preserving message from custom eception: https://github.com/SintefRaufossManufacturing/python-hcn/blob/master/hcn/cy_handler.cpp

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly (which file extension, which necessary imports) you use to declare the cython class and cast it to a `PyObject`? (first codeblock) PyObject is not defined by default and importing it from `"Python.h"` make cython complain that Python objects cannot be casted to primitive types...

Comment: The 1st block (.pyx file) was missing "from cpython.ref cimport PyObject" . I took the liberty to edit it.

Comment: I'm still missing a point: if the .pyx (the one that defines JMapError) has the same name as the .pxd (the one that has +raise_py_error) every works fine with a standard setup.py.  But when they have different names (say because I want to +raise_py_error  from 2 different pxd files), I don't yet have the correct setup.py syntax (depending on what I use, I get "undefined symbol jmaperror" on module import, or doubly defined symbols on compilation.

Comment: Thanks Demi-Lune for the cimport. I use waf to build this (waf's cython support is fairly good) so not sure about setup.py. You should be able to define JMapError in a separate file and include that in both your .pxd files, but I havent tried it.

Comment: I am still having problems on windows. With gcc/clang this works just fine. However with msvc i am getting errors like this ```error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct _object * ParseExceptionT" (__imp_?ParseExceptionT@@3PEAU_object@@EA) referenced in function __catch$?raise_py_error@@YAXXZ$0``` I used PyAPI_DATA macro. Does anyone know what has to be done in order to get this working with msvc?

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I've stumbled into the same problem (on MSVC) as @Nic30g and managed to solve it by prepending `extern "C"` to prevent symbol mangling - so, basically, `extern "C" extern PyObject *jmaperror;`

It seems that `public` on `cdef public PyObject* jmaperror = <PyObject*>JMapError` serves the same purpose - without it, the symbol in the generated .cpp file becomes mangled too.

Answer (score 5):

The default C++ exception handler in Cython should illustrate exactly how to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
static void __Pyx_CppExn2PyErr() {
  // Catch a handful of different errors here and turn them into the
  // equivalent Python errors.
  try {
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
      ; // let the latest Python exn pass through and ignore the current one
    else
      throw;
  } catch (const std::bad_alloc& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::bad_cast& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::domain_error& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::invalid_argument& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& exn) {
    // Unfortunately, in standard C++ we have no way of distinguishing EOF
    // from other errors here; be careful with the exception mask
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::out_of_range& exn) {
    // Change out_of_range to IndexError
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::overflow_error& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::range_error& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::underflow_error& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, exn.what());
  } catch (const std::exception& exn) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, exn.what());
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Unknown exception");
  }
}
```

So you can either `#define __Pyx_CppExn2PyErr your_custom_exn_handler` in an included .h file to override the generic behavior, or use a one-off custom handler as

```
cdef extern from "...":
    void your_exn_throwing_fcn() except +your_custom_exn_handler
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cython's sources, https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/run/cpp_exceptions.pyx they actually implement the `raise_py_error` in a .pyx file. This makes it a lot easier to share error handling between other .pyx files.

A quick solution involves simply 2 files : myerror.pyx :

```
class MyError(RuntimeError):
    "Base class for errors raised from my C++."
    pass
cdef int raise_my_py_error() except *:
    raise MyError("There was a problem")
```

and myerror.pxd :

```
cdef int raise_my_py_error() except *
```

which allows you to add an `except +my_py_error` in all your files.

However, this "loses" the `e.what()` of C++ exceptions. So a more interesting solution needs a couple more helper files :

my_error_helper.h :

```
extern const char* get_my_py_error_message();
```

my_error_helper.cxx :

```
#include <exception>
const char* get_my_py_error_message()
{
  try {
    throw;
  } catch (const my_custom_cxx_exception& e) {
    return e.what();
  }
}
```

my_error_helper.pxd :

```
cdef extern from "my_error_helper.h": 
    const char* get_my_py_error_message()
```

my_error.pxd :

```
cdef int raise_my_py_error() except *
```

my_error.pyx :

```
cimport my_error_helper

class MyError(RuntimeError):
    "Base class for errors raised from my C++."
    pass

cdef int raise_my_py_error() except *:
    msg = my_error_helper.get_my_py_error_message().decode('utf-8')
    raise MyError(msg)
```