# Printing unhandled C++ exception information when running Cython program

Tags: python, c++, cython

When running Python script that makes use of Cython and C++ and an unhandled exception occurs console output doesn't contain any useful information:

```
collecting ... Fatal Python error: Aborted

Current thread 0x00007f0c1f7ec000 (most recent call first):
  File ".../test_program.py", line 29 in test_eval_simple
  File ".../test_program.py", line 31 in <module>
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 168 in exec_module
  ...
```

However if I attach C++ debugger and run the same script an exception information is being printed out which makes debugging much easier:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'af::exception'
  what():  ArrayFire Exception (Invalid input size:203):
In function af::dim4 getOutDims(const af::dim4&, const af::dim4&, bool)
In file src/backend/ArrayInfo.cpp:173
Invalid dimension for argument 1
Expected: ldims == rdims

In function af::array af::operator/(const af::array&, const af::array&)
```

**Is it possible to instruct Cython/Python to produce a more meaningful message and print out C++ exception information by default?**

Comment: Did you instead want to [propagate c++ exception to cython/python exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185213/propagating-c-exception-to-cython-python-exception)?

Comment: This solves the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427339/1008902